# How to use best use Google/Facebook signin using expo AuthSession to authenticate with a custom backend API

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, expo, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I am working on creating an mobile app using Expo (managed workflow). I have a backend server which this app will connect to. The backend server has its own authentication with username and password and all other endpoints are protected based on a token that you would receive by signing in to the API using a /authenticate endpoint.

Now, I would like to add a 'Sign in with Google' feature to my app. From the Expo's AuthSession documentations, it looks like somehow the app can authenticate with Google. I want to use this identity to authenticate with my backend API.

I created a /api/auth/google endpoint in my API that uses passport google-oauth, redirects user to google and get authorization code sent to /api/auth/google/callback. I then use the authorization code to access Google's people API, to get the email to validate the user and respond back with a access token for my API if the Google sign in was successful. This works fine when using in a browser.

I want to do something similar for the react-native app. When I use the Google example in Expo's AuthSession, it gives me back a access_token. I have no idea how it gets an access_token because the app does not know my client secret. But still, I don't know how to use it to login to my API and get my API's token.

I have thought about using AuthSession to directly open my API's /api/auth/google, so it would redirect correctly and my backend can then send my API's token to the app. The problem with this is, when someone clicks on the 'Sign in with Google' button in the app, apple will tell you 'App name wants to use myapi.com to sign in' or something along those lines instead of Google.com. Additionally when I add more sign in options like Sign in with Facebook and Sign in with Something else, the user's phone will always say that the app wants to use myapi.com to sign in and then in turn be redirected to Google/Facebook or something else. I am not sure if this is allowed and would count as misleading the user and get rejected form the app store. I tried logging into some of the apps on my phone and clicking on 'Sign in with Google' tells the app is trying to sign in with Google.com and 'Sign in with Facebook' tells that the app is trying to sign in with Facebook.com correctly. But then I also know that the app eventually authenticates with its own API somehow. I don't know what is the right way to do that.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? Please share your solution